# How to compare digits after find with awk, egrep

Tags: awk, grep

i have some file.txt where is  a lot of information. Input in file looks like:

`<ss>283838<ss>`
.
.
`<ss>111 from 4444<ss>`
.
`<ss>255<ss>`
The numbers can have any number of digits.

1. I need to find and compare these 2 **numbers**
2. If they equal print name of file and print that they are equal if not, reverse meneaning. **Only one string in file have digits with word "from" between**
   I tried to do like

`Awk '/[0-9]+ from./ {print $0} file.txt | egrep -o '[0-9]+'`

With this command i get those two digits, but i im stacked now, and do not know how to compare them

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts(keep it up). Please do share samples of input and expected output to make your question more clear, thank you.

Comment: @User123: Suggest you to edit your question and show your sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Simple explanation would be: getting respective values of digits by regex and then comparing them to check 3 cases either they are greater, lesser or equal to each other, will add detailed explanation in sometime.

```
awk '
match($0,/<[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+/){
  val1=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/[^0-9]*/,"",val1)
  match($0,/[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+>/)
  val2=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/[^0-9]*/,"",val2)
  if(val1>val2){
     print "val1("val1 ")is  Greater than val2("val2")"
  }
  if(val2>val1){
     print "val2("val2 ")is  Greater than val1("val1")"
  }
  if(val1==val2){
     print "val1("val1 ")is equals to val2("val2")"
  }
}' Input_file
```

For your current shown sample output will be as follows:

```
val2(333)is  Greater than val1(222)
```

Comment: The problem is that for example "<ss>222 from 333<\ss>" only one, but there lot of strings that start "<ss>" and those digits can be from 0 to n

Comment: @User123, ok edited code now, please do check it once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: @User123, yes my edited code will take care of it, please check it once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I will check it in 1 hour, and let u know, ty for your help.

Comment: Ty for your help, with little modification this work perfectly, ty.

Comment: Hi one more time, i try to use this script for all .txt files in folder DIR="/home/me/Desktop/test" for file in "$DIR" do awk '{(then goes script)} ' done. but it doesnt work, just stucks without error

Comment: @User123, actually code is written by keeping 1 file in mind. Try mentioning `*.txt` in place of `Input_file` in above code, you need not to run this in a loop, let me know how it goes, cheers.